# Selenium click right on mouse or press option key form keyboard

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc

Using selenium how can I click on the right click of mouse or press on the option key from keyboard(This key is usually available between right <kbd>ALT</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to open the context menu, there is a `selenium.contextMenu(locator)` . This is the menu that opens up when you right click or press that option key.

This example shows you how to open a page element in a new tab from context menu. The page used for example is seleniumhq.org. This code will right click on the logo link and open the page in a new tab

```
selenium.contextMenu(link=Selenium);

//In the below line of code "t" is the shortcut to open the page in a new tab
selenium.keyPress("link=Selenium","t");
```

Hope this helps.[image]

Comment: so after that we have to use slenium.click(locator) to click on one menu item?

Comment: Rather than clicking on the menu, you can use short cut keys to select the value. I have updated my answer with an example

Comment: just a small confusion for this selenium.keyPress("link=Selenium","t"); how this shortcut key "t" keySequence is defind ?

Comment: In the example given above, that is defined in firefox browser application code.

Comment: How about posting a screenshot of the context menu which you are working on? That would make it easier

Comment: 1-AJ how can i post a screenshot here.is there any way??           2- If we take same example u have given for  selenium.keyPress("link=Selenium","t"); on http://seleniumhq.org/ page . From where this "t" comes. I went through api it ask for key sequence...

Comment: You can edit your question and add a screenshot. If you check the screenshot which i have posted, in the context menu for every option there is a letter which is underlined. For "open in new tab" it "t". This acts like a shortcut.

Comment: Thanks a lot AJ for this help...,1-I have checked in firefox, it is working in firefox only not in IE so is it browser dependent?. 2- Is there any url or info so that i can know the list of short cut keys

Comment: IE doesn't provide those shortcuts. Need to find a different way to select the option in context menu. Sorry that at this point I dont have an answer for that

Comment: Thanks a lot lot lot for you help and support..& sorry as i have to earn reputation to paste a image. Thanks a lot again.