# Chrome extension testing

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, google-chrome-extension, integration-testing, chromium

Does anyone have experience with Chrome extension testing?

For example:

> I want to create an extension that uses the
>   popup browser action, and automate a test case that checks the
>   behavior of the popup when clicked.[[chromium issue](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=84219)]

Perhaps you could use selenium (it would be really great if this is possible).

Comment: Are you looking for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6176033/selenium-click-right-on-mouse-or-press-option-key-form-keyboard/6176106#6176106

Comment: No. There is so called "browser actions", and I want to have access to browser action popup. http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/browserAction.html

Comment: Chromium's python automation tool, PyAuto, currently does not support this.  If you want to change your profession and help develop this missing feature (in C++...), you should probably start here: http://src.chromium.org/svn/trunk/src/chrome/test/automation/extension_proxy.cc http://src.chromium.org/svn/trunk/src/chrome/test/pyautolib/pyautolib.cc

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered using a general purpose GUI-testing tool? If you are looking for a free, basic solution, check out [Sikuli](http://sikuli.org/). There is a bunch of similar tools out there.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to such interesting tool. I must look closer on it. It's fun. I have found useful blog about it(Sikuli + Java + Maven + CI): http://javasplitter.blogspot.com/2011/02/continuous-gui-integration-testing.html

Answer (score 0):

I've gotten some mileage using [protractor](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/) to navigate to the url for the popup and running tests on it as if it were a regular page.